# Select IDs not found in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Say I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5);
```

How would I make that select the IDs I've provided that are not found in Parts?

I guess something like this:

```
SELECT (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5) WHERE NOT IN Parts.PartID
```

Im not trying to select from the Parts table. I'm trying to select from my ID array and compare it against the Parts table to find the IDs from the ID array that are not in the Parts table. So say the Parts table has id2, id3, id4 in it, the query would return id1 and id5

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a single query like this, with an anti-join:

```
SELECT ids.id FROM (SELECT 'id1' AS id
                    UNION SELECT 'id2'
                    UNION SELECT 'id3'
                    UNION SELECT 'id4'
                    UNION SELECT 'id5') ids
LEFT JOIN Parts p
  ON p.PartID = ids.id
WHERE p.PartID IS NULL
```

Comment: @wilsotobianco, this will generally perform better than a "WHERE ... NOT IN ..."

Answer (score 1):

You need your list of ID's in a table object or a subquery that you can then query against:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 AS (
SELECT 'id1' AS PartID
UNION
SELECT 'id2'
UNION 
SELECT 'id3'
UNION
SELECT 'id4'
UNION 
SELECT 'id5'
)
```

Then you can use `NOT EXISTS` to find items from your list not in the `Parts` table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Parts b
                  WHERE a.PartID = b.PartID)
```

I don't know MySQL terribly well, nor how your list is being introduced into the query, but you could likely turn the array into a table more elegantly than manually creating it.

Answer (score 0):

You miss to provide  table name

```
  SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5);
```

or try like this:

```
 select * from parts 
 where partid not in(SELECT ID FROM Parts WHERE PartID NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5));
```

Comment: This will show parts that don't match the provided list, not show which of the provided list don't match the table, which I believe is what the OP requested.

Comment: This gives Ids in parts that's not found in my id array. I want ids from the id array not in the parts table.

Comment: @LeeJacobson:- Updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for? Else please explain more?

Comment: @R.T. That's still not right. I'm not trying to select from the Parts table. I'm trying to select from my ID array and compare it against the Parts table to find the IDs from the ID array that are not in the Parts table.

So say the Parts table has id2, id3, id4 in it, the query would return id1 and id5

Comment: @LeeJacobson:- SQL Server doesnt support array. Can you tell how you are storing your ID array?

Comment: @R.T. I guess that's the problem then. I think Goat CO's answer below is the only way this would work, but it's really messy. I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: @LeeJacobson:- Yes that is the easy way. If you dont have a value stored somewhere then it is the only option! And that is the easiest way :)

Comment: View my answer, maybe that solves the problem? Not the most elegant solution but still...

Answer (score -1):

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID NOT IN (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5);
```

or maybe

```
SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartID NOT EXISTS (id1, id2, id3, id4, id5);
```

Comment: This gives Ids in parts that's not found in my id array. I want ids from the id array not in the parts table.

Comment: You aren't explaining yourself properly, is there another field called ID in a different table? because then you have to use a JOIN of some sort

Comment: I'm sorry; let me try again. I'm have an array I've IDs and I want to find out which of those IDs are not in the database. If I do a NOT IN I get the IDs in the Parts table not in the ID array. I want the opposite, the IDs in the ID array not in the Parts table. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ID FROM Parts WHERE PartID != 'id1' AND PartID != 'id2'... etc
```

Now if you're passing in a dynamic array from, say, C#, you would have to do some string handling and a for loop (for each id) to create the SQL Syntax, which is actually fairly simple.

I know this is basically *hard coding*... but it seems to be the simplest way to do this.